# HTML form javascript to associate question, answer and feedback

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a language quiz in an HTML form When the user checks their entry, feedback is inserted into  cell in the form of a tick or cross icon . My problem is that the feedback is always inserted into the first td whether the first or second question is answered and checked. Question and appropriate answer are associated with elementNo: I can't figure out how to associate the "mark" cell with the its answer and question

```
<SCRIPT>

//Define the answers. 
Answer = new Array( "Die Maus ist weiss.", "",     
                    "Auf Wiedersehen!");              

//inserts icon, however only in the first element named "mark".
// Somehow needs to select correct place according to element number

function itemfeedback (elementNo)
      {
       if (document.E1a.elements[elementNo].value == "")
        {
        alert("You must type an answer!");
        }

        else if (document.E1a.elements[elementNo].value == Answer[elementNo])
        {
          document.getElementById("mark").innerHTML = "<img src='correct.jpg'>";
        }
          else
          {
            document.getElementById("mark").innerHTML = "<img src='incorrect.jpg'>";
          }
      }

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

    <FORM NAME="E1a" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" onReset="return confirm('Clear entries? Are you sure?')">

  <HR>
  <H3>
  translate, remembering punctuation and capitalisation...
  </H3>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>1. The mouse is white.</td>
  <td><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Q1" SIZE=50 MAXLENGTH=50></td>
  <td><INPUT TYPE="button" id ="check_button" VALUE="check..." NAME="B1" onClick="itemfeedback(0)"></td>
  <td id="mark"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>2. Good-bye!</td>
  <td><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Q2" SIZE=50 MAXLENGTH=50></td> 
  <td><INPUT TYPE="button"id ="check_button"  VALUE="check..." NAME="B2" onClick="itemfeedback(2)"></td>
  <td id="mark"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>

  <INPUT TYPE="RESET" id ="reset_fields" VALUE="Clear Entries">

  </CENTER>

  </FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I hope that my question is clear and that someone will help.

Comment: You can't have duplicate IDs for elements in HTML. IDs must be unique for each mark td.

Comment: Is there no way to associate the element number with the id?

Comment: Use class instead of id and use `elementNo` to index that element within the class collection

Comment: I guess there are pretty much examples for that in StackOverflow. This is a question asked multiple times.

Comment: I do not understand how to use class instead of id in my example.  Would you mind explaining, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Quick Answer

ID's are intended to be unique within a HTML document according to [HTML5 specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute).  Because of this, all instances of an ID after the first occurrence are ignored by JavaScripts "getElementById" function.  A more proper way to select multiple DOM elements is to use the "class" attribute, like this:

```html
<td class="mark"></td>
...
<td class="mark"></td>
```

And reference it using JavaScript, using "getElementsByClassName"

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mark')
```

#### More Helpful Answer

I would make a couple more suggestions, to make your code a bit more dynamic, and functional. I have inserted comments in the code below to explain the changes/suggestions I have.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script>

  // We will use an object instead of an array, so that we can reference the answers by a string, rather then an integer.  
  // Also, any time a NEW variable is defined, it should be prefaced with "let" or "const" for >= ES2015, or "var" for < ES2015 (see https://codeburst.io/javascript-wtf-is-es6-es8-es-2017-ecmascript-dca859e4821c for details on the different script versions)
  const answer = {
    Q1: "Die Maus ist weiss.",
    Q2: "Auf Wiedersehen!"
  };

  // itemfeedback function is now passing the input id, rather than the index
  function itemfeedback (id) {
    // This will get the input, associated with the button
    let input  = document.getElementById(id),
    // This will be the ID of the mark element that is associated with the submitted input
        markId = "mark" + id,
    // This is the mark element assocaited with the submitted input
        mark   = document.getElementById(markId);

    if (input.value == "") {
      alert("You must type an answer!");
    } 
    // Since we have assigned the answers to an object, and gave each of the answers indexes to match the input ids, we can find the answer by that
    else if (input.value == answer[id]){
      mark.innerHTML = "<img src='correct.jpg'>";
    } else {
      mark.innerHTML = "<img src='incorrect.jpg'>";
    }
  }

  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <form NAME="E1a" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" onReset="return confirm('Clear entries? Are you sure?')">

    <HR>
    <H3>
      translate, remembering punctuation and capitalisation...
    </H3>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>1. The mouse is white.</td>
        <!-- Gave input ID of "Q1" -->
        <td><input TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Q1" SIZE=50 MAXLENGTH=50 id="Q1"></td>
        <!-- Changed id to class, since it is non-unique -->
        <td><input TYPE="button" class="check_button" value="check..." NAME="B1" onClick="itemfeedback('Q1')"></td>
        <!-- We will give this an ID that can be associated with it's related inputs name attribute -->
        <td id="markQ1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2. Good-bye!</td>
        <!-- Gave input ID of "Q2" -->
        <td><input TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Q2" SIZE=50 MAXLENGTH=50 id="Q2"></td> 
        <!-- Passed ID to onChange handler, instead of index.  Also hanged id to class, since it is non-unique -->
        <td><input TYPE="button" class="check_button"  value="check..." NAME="B2" onClick="itemfeedback('Q2')"></td>
        <!-- We will give this an ID that can be associated with it's related inputs name attribute -->
        <td id="markQ2"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>

    <input TYPE="RESET" id="reset_fields" value="Clear Entries">

  </center>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

#### EDIT for Form Reset

Place this function to remove images from form onReset:

```html
<!-- We are now calling a function to be executed, and the returned value of the function will determine if the form itself is cleared.  A negative blue will not, a positive value will -->
<form NAME="E1a" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" onReset="return clearForm(this)">
```

```js
function clearForm (form) { 
    // Get option that is pressed
    var clear = confirm('Clear entries? Are you sure?');
    // If positive option is clicked, the form will be reset
    if (clear) {
      // This will select all images within the document
      var markImgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
      // Iterates through each image, and removes it from the dom     
      while (markImgs[0]) markImgs[0].parentNode.removeChild(markImgs[0])
    }

    return clear;
}
```

Comment: THank you very much. I shall go through very carefully what you were kind enough to suggest. An especial thanks for the comments to explain the code, sometimes the examples on stackoverflow are difficult to comprehend for a non-programmer like myself. The trouble is I am not a programmer, just trying to make a language tutor for my own use. So new to this.

Comment: May I ask one more question about this code. The reset clears the form input field, but does not remove the correct or incorrect image inserted in field class = "mark". I guess that this is not an input field and therefore does not clear with onReset? How can I deal with that?

Comment: You can change the "onReset" handler that is on the form, to a function, like this: onReset="clearForm(this)".  The function would look something like this:

Comment: Thank you. Phew! Your code is complex - still trying to get my head around the concepts. Perfect though!

Comment: function clearForm (form) { 
    // Get option that is pressed
    var clear = confirm('Clear entries? Are you sure?');
    // If positive option is clicked, the form will be reset
    if (clear) {
      // This will select all images within the document
      var markImgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
      // Iterates through each image, and removes it from the dom     
      while (markImgs[0]) markImgs[0].parentNode.removeChild(markImgs[0])
    }

    return clear;
  }

Comment: I know that last comment is kinda crunched, but hopefully it isn't too confusing.  It is a function that will need placed in the script tag.  Glad I could help! :-)